# Youtube Video Search API : Filter by tag broken?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the following API call to pull all of the videos with `<TAG>` from `<CHANNEL>`:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<CHANNEL>/uploads/-/<TAG>/?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published
```

But for some tag names the results are wrong, or even empty. For example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NintendoFR/uploads/-/n3ds/?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published
```

only has 1 result, but I know that there are at least 20 videos with the tag "n3ds", on the other hand

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NintendoFR/uploads/-/wiiu/?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published
```

gives the expected 36 results. Any ideas? Or anyone with similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem (search by tag no longer works).

The Youtube API team has history for making un-announced changes.

For example, a few month's back, the "video description" field was truncated 
- without any announcement of the change
- without updating the doco to reflect the change

This looks like a similar change, i.e. tag search has been depreciated (switched off).

Workaround (for your videos) is to include the tag(s) in the first 150 chars or so of the video's description.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem. A few days or weeks ago, a piece of code that sends these requests stopped delivering results. After a bit of research, we found out that getting results is random:

- On some occasions we get the right results
- On some occasions we get no results.

The only difference we could find in both requests is that a parameter is missing from the requests. When requesting an answer in XML, in the feed node an item is missing:

```
    <feed xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'></feed>
```

Although we do not know why this is, at least now you know that you are not the only one that has this problem.

Comment: I've reported the issue, let's see if the do something ... https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4269

Comment: For now, we are able to get a video by a specific tag through the Zend Gdata library. We fetch all videos for a specific user, and check for every video if it has the tag we seek.

For reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#AuthSub_for_Web_Applications